# Many to Many in Access

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to ether get rid of a real world many-to-many relationship (and just feeling stupid for not being able to) or find the proper way to input it into Access.  I've tried several junction table setups and only seem to pass the many-to-many problem on to another table.

Here is an abbreviated sample of the two tables:

Table 1:

```
Amp_Number      Amp_S.Name
103             Rag1
194             Osd4
230             Lew6
321             Ooi4
550             Qwd3
629             Crd5
687             Rab4
879             Pra2
```

Table 2:

```
Plas_Number         Plas_Amp
55                  Rab4
82                  Osd4 & Qwd3 & Lew6
94                  Rab4 & Rag1 & Ooi4
102                 Ooi4 & Lew6
125                 Pra2 & Rag1 & Crd5
142                 Qwd3 & Ooi4 & Rag1
146                 Lew6 & Osd4 & Rab4
154                 Rab4 & Lew6 & Ooi4
```

Comment: What is the result you want ?

Comment: The example shows only up to n=3 Amps per Plas, but in reality the number could be 0 to infinity, though it's not likely to be above 20.

Comment: If there is a solution, a set of tables where there were nothing but one to many relationships, instead of the many to many relationship I have (each Plas can have multiple Amp and each Amp is on many Plas). @grahamj42

Comment: Are the values in Plas_Amp stored in a single column (delimited with " & " as above) or are multiple columns storing these values such as Plas_Amp1, Plas_Amp2, Plas_Amp3, ...?

Comment: @Taliesin They are as written.  I'm inheriting them from someone who's long gone in csv format with columns delimited with commas.  I could understand if there were two delimiters, but I don't know what they came from.  I'm just trying to move from spreadsheets into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a junction table mapping the `Plas_Number` to `Amp_Number`, which can have one or more records for either Table 1 or Table 2:

Table 1:

```
Amp_Number      Amp_S.Name
103             Rag1
194             Osd4
230             Lew6
321             Ooi4
550             Qwd3
629             Crd5
687             Rab4
879             Pra2
```

Table 2:

```
Plas_Number
55
82
94
102
125
142
146
154
```

Junction Table:

```
Plas_Number    Amp_Number
55             687
82             194
82             550
82             230
etc.
```

- There is a one-to-many between Table 1 and Junction Table
- There is a one-to-many between Table 2 and Junction Table

Comment: Thanks, just slow today.  For some reason I excluded this answer as Plas_number and Amp_number are both replicated in this junction table, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: That's what a junction table is by definition.  It uses the key value from two tables to link rows together.