# Access - Having trouble assigning multiple roles to the same person

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a small database for my church and am having a few issues.  this is my first real project outside of a classroom setting.  I have multiple different positions, such as elder, teacher, and worship team, and a user may have more than one position.  How would I set this up?  I made a table for each role that has a unique ID.  I thought about making a separate table for each role that would use the members ID as a primary key in the table for each individual position but can't seem to get that to work in Access.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot of questions and resources regarding many-to-many relationships, such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347722/many-to-many-in-access) or [this Microsoft page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-many-to-many-relationships-e65bcc53-8e1c-444a-b4fb-1c0b8c1f5653). What have you tried, and what is your exact issue?

Comment: Thanks for you help in pointing me into the right direction.  I was able to figure i out.